# Sublime Text 3 Default Packages Disabling

Tags: performance, customization, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there any performance benefit to disabling some of the default languages and packages in Sublime Text that I don't use.  For example, I don't program much in `D`, `R`,`Erlang`,or `Groovy`; is it worth my time to disable them?

And in general, are there any other obvious performance boosts available for Sublime?  It's not running slow per se, but seems to be slower than it used to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling packages wouldn't make a performance difference unless the package that you have installed is actively doing something while you are working. So it's probably a waste of time to remove any packages.

If you are looking for speed improvements, I have just jumped onto a SSD and that has made a world of difference for speed.